# OR and AND Operators in Elasticsearch query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have few json document with the following format :-

```
    _source: {
            userId: "A1A1",
            customerId: "C1",
            component: "comp_1",
            timestamp: 1408986553,
     }
```

I want to query the document based on the following :-

```
(( userId == currentUserId) OR ( customerId== currentCustomerId) OR (currentRole ==ADMIN) )  AND component= currentComponent)
```

I tried using the SearchSourceBuilder and QueryBuilders.matchQuery, but I wasnt able to put multiple sub queries with AND and OR operators.

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("userId",userId)).sort("timestamp", SortOrder.DESC).size(count);
```

How we query elasticsearch using OR and AND operators?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think in this case the [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) is the best shot.

Something like :

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : { "term" : { "component" : "comp_1" } },
        "should" : [
            { "term" : { "userId" : "A1A1" } },
            { "term" : { "customerId" : "C1" } },
            { "term" : { "currentRole" : "ADMIN" } }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```

Which gives in Java:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
    .boolQuery()
    .must(termQuery("component", currentComponent))
    .should(termQuery("userId", currentUserId))
    .should(termQuery("customerId", currentCustomerId))
    .should(termQuery("currentRole", ADMIN))
    .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
```

The `must` parts are `AND`s, the `should` parts are more or less `OR`s, except that you can specify a minimum number of `should`s to match (using `minimum_should_match`), this minimum being 1 by default I think (but you could set it to 0, meaning that a document matching no `should` condition would be returned as well).

If you want to do more complex queries involving nested `AND`s and `OR`s, simply nest other bool queries inside `must` or `should` parts.

Also, as you're looking for exact values (ids and so on), maybe you can use [term queries instead of match queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html), which spare you the analysis phase (if those fields are analyzed at all, which doesn't necessarily make sense for ids). If they are analyzed, you still can do that, but only if you know exactly how your terms are stored ([standard analyzer stores them lower cased for instance](https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/#why-isnt-my-search-returning-what-i-expect)).

Comment: `.minimumShouldMatch` takes a string only as an argument, right?

Comment: @malte You're right. In this case it should be `minimumNumberShouldMatch` with an `int`, or `minimumShouldMatch` with a `string`. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a [`query_string` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), your ANDs and ORs will be interpreted as such by the Lucene library.

This allows you to search for

```
(currentUserId OR currentCustomerId) AND currentComponent
```

for instance. By default, the values will be searched for in all fields.

Comment: But something like `QueryBuilders.queryString("(userId: "+currentUserId+" OR customerId: "+currentCustomerId+" OR currentRole: "+ADMIN+")  AND component: "+currentComponent+")")` should work the way intended.

Comment: from the linked page of ElasticSearch documentation : "The default field for query terms if no prefix field is specified. Defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to _all." Apparently, ElasticSearch adds the _all field at index time, to which we can then apply Lucene syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of query with AND, OR and NOT:

```
GET cities/_search
{
  "query": {"bool": {"must": [
    {"bool": {"should": [
      {"bool": {"must": [
        {"match": {"description": "great"}},
        {"match": {"description": "orange"}}
      ]}},
      {"match": {"description": "popular"}}
    ]}},

    {"bool": {"must_not": [
      {"match": {"description": "poor"}}
    ]}},

    {"bool": {"should": [
      {"match": {"city": "London"}},
      {"match": {"city": "Paris"}},
    ]}}
  ]}},
"size": 20,
"from": 0
}
```

It searches among specified cities only cities, which description includes ("great" AND "orange") OR "popular" words but excludes results, where "poor" word found

`must` means **AND**, `should` means **OR**, `must_not` means **NOT**

Other examples you can find [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query):